# firefox image position different to chrome

Tags: css, image, firefox, google-chrome, position

[solved - issue was related to web tools provided by ucoz]

Comment: Code please! Also your website sounds sort of pervy. :P

Comment: My first guess is that you are using tables for layout instead of CSS. Do you realize that hasn't been the standard since prior to Google Chrome's first launch?

Comment: It's some kind of unholy mix between a table and div based layout

Answer (score 2):

Your webpage lacks a doctype.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` should be the first thing in the HTML.

Then use the HTML validator provided by the W3C to fix up your HTML http://validator.w3.org.

Answer (score 1):

You should invest in a reset stylesheet to normalize the elements across browsers. Try plugging this into your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css">
```